# How to dynamically change column name on model creating in Entity Framework context class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dbcontext, ef-fluent-api

I have a base class like that:

```
public class BaseClass : IEditableObject {

    public BaseClass() {

    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public void BeginEdit() {

    }
    public void CancelEdit() {

    }
    public void EndEdit() {

    }
}
```

And I have 2 derived classes like that:

```
public class User : BaseClass {

    [Column( "UserFirstName" )]
    public string FirstName {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Column( "UserLastName" )]
    public string LastName {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

public class School : BaseClass {
    [Column( "SchoolName" )]
    public string Name {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I am using Entity Framework Code-First and configuring these classes in my context class:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext {

    public MyContext() : base() {
        Database.SetInitializer( new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>() );
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    public DbSet<School> Schools { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating( DbModelBuilder modelBuilder ) {
        base.OnModelCreating( modelBuilder );
    }

}
```

When I run the program database and tables are created but primary key column names are **Id** for each table. I want the column name to be **UserId** or **SchoolId**.

Therefore I must configure entities on model creating to change column names with **TableNameId**

I could do this job as well:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property( i => i.Id ).HasColumnName( "UserId" );
modelBuilder.Entity<School>().Property( i => i.Id ).HasColumnName( "SchoolId" );
```

Assume that I have hundreds of classes, I'll make configurations one by one for each entity so this is a huge waste of time.

How can I do this job dynamically using iterate or something else I don't know?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`DbModelBuilder.Types<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbmodelbuilder.types(v=vs.113).aspx#M:System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Types%60%601) method to apply your custom convention on all `BaseClass` derived entities:

```
modelBuilder.Types<BaseClass>().Configure(c => 
    c.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName(c.ClrType.Name + "Id")
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Ivan. It is the answer for my situation.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Custom Code First Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819164(v=vs.113).aspx) for this. In your case:

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p => p.Name == "Id")
            .Configure(c => c.HasColumnName(c.ClrPropertyInfo.ReflectedType.Name + "Id"));
```

Comment: I tried your solution but column names are BaseId now.

Comment: Ah yes, please see the modification.

Comment: You've posted this when I was preparing mine, so I was wondering if I should post it since it's basically another variation of your answer. At the end decided to post it for the record :) +1

Comment: That's OK! I think your solution is cleaner when OP wants to have the convention for the BaseClass subtypes only, mine would be for any Id property. Now OP has options, great!